# Jenkins won't start after plugin installation *and does not log anything*

Tags: jenkins, debian

I installed Jenkins' Gradle plugin and used the automatic restart option via the Jenkins web interface. Jenkins seemed to hang on the "restarting..." page, so I finally tried to manually restart the Jenkins service on the server (64-bit Debian 7) using `service jenkins restart`.

Now, Jenkins is no longer running at all (verified with `ps -ef | grep -i [J]enkins` and `service jenkins status`), and when I try `service jenkins [re]start`, I see an `[ ok ]` message but nothing else seems to happen. I've deleted `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, and each time I try a `service start` (or restart), the log file reappears, but it's blank (`ls -lA` shows that the file was recently made, but `cat` produces no output). I also tried rebooting the server, with no effect. I finally deleted the `Gradle` folders under `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`, which also did not appear to make a difference.

How do I even begin to approach this problem? Should I just re-install Jenkins?

**EDIT:** System info:

```
> uname -a
Linux AUC-Workstation1 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

According to `dpkg -l`, I'm using Debian's `jenkins` package, version `1.617`.

**EDIT 2:** I'm actually using the `jenkins` package provided directly by Jenkins, as per the instructions [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu).

Answer (score 5):

I just had a problem where multiple Jenkins plugins were breaking Jenkins startup (after an upgrade) and here is the procedure I followed to resolve the issue, which might work for other plugin startup issues.

I'm working on an Ubuntu server, but I expect that this would work for Debian if it's going to work at all - I encourage others to adjust the procedure:

1. logged into the server and switched to the jenkins user (`sudo su jenkins` in my case)
2. went to the main jenkins directory
3. renamed plugins to plugins.problems_YYYYMMDD

   - previously, I attempted to disable the plugins, but this did not work for me (system still would not start)
4. created an empty directory plugins
5. restarted jenkins (`sudo service jenkins restart`)

   - In my case, this started just fine
6. iteratively followed the following procedure to add plugins back in

   1. copied 1 or more plugins from plugins.problems_YYYYMMDD/ to plugins/
   2. restarted jenkins
   3. went to the plugin center and installed updates as available

      - sometimes I needed to install updates in a particular order due to dependencies
7. evaluated results in 'Manage Old Data'

   - I think I'm facing some manual updates of the old data

Note: if you know which plugins are likely the problem, then it is easier to just disable or temporarily (re)move them rather than (re)moving all of the plugins!

Comment: Interesting. I did try getting rid of just the Gradle plugin folder, but I don't think I tried deleting all the plugin folder contents. And once I got Jenkins working again, I re-installed the Gradle plugin because it's a necessary part of our build, and everything worked swimmingly.

Comment: I was able to re-install all of my plugins - once I got the order right - and they even managed to upgrade all of my "old data".  Woot!  (In fact, the "old data" revealed the dependencies that I had broken.)

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. It didn't even occur to me that the order of the plugins might affect the behavior.

Comment: It did not occur to me either until I stumbled across it  - quite luckily!

Answer (score 0):

I never did figure out the initial problem, but I did get Jenkins working again, sort of.

I uninstalled Jenkins (using `apt-get purge`) and then re-installed it. This time it failed to start because it needed Java 7, but I apparently only had Java 6 installed (this surprised me, because I thought I had previously configured Jenkins to use Java 7 on that machine). So I installed `openjdk-7-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre`, set `JAVA` and `JAVA_HOME` appropriately in the Jenkins config file, and started the service again. This allowed Jenkins to start.